# When should [specific-question] Meta questions be closed as "can no longer be reproduced"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, meta

[*I can't add an answer to a closed question: what other solutions do I have?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365603/2751851) was briefly closed as "off-topic/can no longer be reproduced". To my eyes, the closure was mistaken, for the following reasons:

- This [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) question readily lends itself to discussion of a general issue: the phrasing of the title itself suggests it, and the answers are primarily concerned with offering general advice.
- Even if the question didn't explicitly invite a general discussion, it might be useful as a precedent in future Meta questions, or even as a duplicate target. That the specific issue has been solved wouldn't get in the way, as the relevant facts can be easily reconstituted through post histories and timelines. All that closing the Meta question in this way achieves is signalling the specific issue has been solved, something which I don't find truly helpful — after all, to whom are we signalling it?
- "Off-topic/can no longer be reproduced" seems more obviously applicable in Meta to [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [support](/questions/tagged/support) questions, and even in such cases it tends to signal the issue is irrelevant, and not that it has been solved. As evidence, consider [the large number of open questions tagged both [bug] and [status-completed]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D+%5Bstatus-completed%5D+closed%3Ano).

Given the considerations above, I find it hard to think of a situation in which it would be justified to close a [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) question as "off-topic/can no longer be reproduced", save for questions that exist solely because of a grammatical misunderstanding (those being the Meta analogues of typo questions in the main site). Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Meta has closed specific-question posts as "can no longer be reproduced" before, so it is a thing even if it isn't common. Ex: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299799/what-should-be-done-with-this-thoroughly-off-topic-highly-voted-question (I used [this query](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bspecific-question%5D+closed%3Ayes+duplicate%3Ano) but can't search for specific close reasons.)

Comment: As for your first point, maybe the OP of the question would be willing to edit it a bit so that it's not about that specific question but just uses it as an example.

Comment: A temporary outage of the SO web server is the standard example.

Comment: @BSMP "maybe the OP of the question would be willing to edit it a bit so that it's not about that specific question but just uses it as an example" -- I feel that is unnecessary in this case. The general question reveals itself straightforwardly enough in that post as it currently stands. The example isn't really getting in the way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not a forum. We don't use closure of questions as a "done" checkmark.

Meta questions about specific questions should remain open, even if the problem at hand was resolved, so people can add additional information or discussion after the fact.

Because yeah, you're discussing a specific question, but the concepts that apply to that specific question and its moderation could apply to other questions as well. Also, new insights could arise and need to be posted.

Comment: "This is not a forum. We don't use closure of questions as a "done" checkmark." -- That sums it up really well.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm one of the close voters, I'll describe what went through my mind as I voted to close.

- I clicked on the link to the question in question.  When *I* saw it, the question in question was [re]open[ed].
- Believing that the main premise of the question was addressed - the question in question was reopened and a new answer could be added - I couldn't see the rationale for the Meta post.
- As we've done in the past, I elected to close it as "can no longer be produced", since...

  - This concerned [a *specific* question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/365603/1), even if the more general phrasing [was later shoehorned in](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/365603/2).
  - The question in question was reopened, and the specific pain point had been addressed, allowing the OP to post a new answer.

At *worst*, it probably should've been closed as a duplicate, since the more general answer is part-and-parcel the same:  "talk about it on Meta and get folks to overturn the close vote," and I am confident that there are dozens of those types of questions floating around.  I don't believe that this particular closure was an overstepping of boundaries, since it *genuinely* seemed like...well...there's no problem here.

Of course, this was me in the morning after thinking about it for about five or so minutes.  I *could've* been wrong, which is why it's fine for the community to overturn decisions like this.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I still feel that a discussion about a specific question can remain relevant even after the incident that led to it has been handled, and that closing it after the "pain point" has been addressed doesn't give much of an useful signal. You may well be right about there being a duplicate somewhere in Meta, though.

Comment: @duplode:  Honestly I didn't see the signal here in that this was really, and originally about a single topic with a single pain point.  It happens enough that yes, the dupe would suffice and should exist at this point.  More to the main hue-and-cry of the post, I didn't see any actual actionable items there which is why I *still* feel like its closure is warranted.  Again, I'm fine with being overruled/wrong on this, but this is my gut feeling here.

Answer (score 0):

The nature itself of the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag which is "to discuss an issue", and issues can be unclear or too broad or way too opinion based or off topic, but never non-reproducible.

Issues can be rehashed in several points of views, and only when those point of views, with all their bells and whistles (aka, attenuating relevant context), have been already rehashed we use the duplicate close reason.

When we use [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question), [specific-answer](/questions/tagged/specific-answer), [specific-edit](/questions/tagged/specific-edit) or [specific-user](/questions/tagged/specific-user) we refer that the matter is *related to* that and we are trying to figure out how to handle them. Such discussions can be rekindled again and again, be used for references in similar situations and can be used as platform to establish a guideline.

Given the above, the issue discussed *is reproducible* just by the reasoning that whenever we find ourselves in the same or similar situation we *will* consult these discussions to obtain wisdom of the ancients.

No reproducible seems to be meant for the bug tracker aspect of meta, which lets remember is one of the [many functions that meta.SO have](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365235/792066) so I believe such close reason should only be used in the context of the bug tracking aspect of meta, and not on the other 5 (?) which meta provides.

Comment: I like the sense in which you use "reproducible" here -- a Meta issue is reproduced whenever other users put themselves into a similar situation. On the last paragraph, I believe it also makes sense to close some [support] questions as non-reproducible (e.g. server outage ones, [as Hans Passant notes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365618/when-should-specific-question-meta-questions-be-closed-as-can-no-longer-be-re/365682#comment571472_365618)).