# How do I deal with my dangerously poor accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-answer

Back when I first became active on Stack Overflow, I was in the habit of answering poor questions and/or duplicates (I've wised up from the experience, sorry about that!). Some answers to these questions were rather poor themselves, but were unfortunate enough to not be downvoted. Some of these answers were so unfortunate that they were actually marked accepted by OP.

This meta is regarding [one such answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44707270/4909087) that I would like to delete, but cannot (because it has been accepted).

To any regular in the Python tag, this question is an obvious duplicate (dynamically creating variables), and the idiomatic answer is to use a dictionary. However, being new to the language, I wrote what I can only call the worst possible answer to the question, and it was accepted shortly thereafter (and with an upvote!). Thankfully, the vote has been undone, because that notification alerted me that horrible delete-worthy content like this still exists under my name.

Now, given the question is a duplicate, and that the answer is mine and has been accepted, what are my possible options?

1. Flag for moderator attention, explain the situation, and hope a moderator with expertise in Python is kind enough to delete?
2. Ping the OP and ask them to unaccept so I can delete (they aren't very active)?
3. Add a disclaimer that this is a dangerous answer (kind of already done) and link to the correct one below?
4. Do any or more of the above and secretly hope that the meta effect kicks in here to get rid of either the question or answer or both?

Comment: I think we just need to keep it. We need posts to make fun of those high-reps ...

Comment: Point 3 though.. You should put it at the **top** of your answer with explanation rather than barely noticeable at the bottom. Say why it's not a good idea and then say "original answer is as follows" and lead into it.

Comment: *"Back when I first became active on Stack Overflow"* - member for three years, this answer is from late June 2017. Hmm ;) I'm just playing, respect for wanting to do the right thing. But there is far more wrong here, your self-proclaimed dangerous answer is not downvoted into oblivion to back that up. If its true, the system is failing on a larger scale here.

Comment: @Gimby if you look at his activity history, that's exactly when he started to become active on SO. So all these 80k rep points were gained in the last year only. Well done @coldspeed!

Comment: In this example, I would either change to, *or add*, another duplicate which has the dictionary method. Really, it's the only way :). But well done @coldspeed for the good citizenship.

Comment: Why not edit it to improve? Remove the current answer and give what you believe is the best possible solution?

Comment: @Will the other answer already says it. Is it really right to edit and repeat what they say?

Comment: Well, you could always edit to point to the other answer... Anyhow, that's how I'd do it. Or I'd flag and bellyache to the mods about how awful my answer is, ratcheting up the drama level every sentence until I'M LITTERALLY BEGGING ON MY KNEES PUT THIS SORRY EXCUSE FOR AN ANSWER DOWN! DON'T YOU SEE ITS SUFFERING, YOU ANIMALS? KILL IT!

Comment: @ChrisF Please, do not abuse your gold badge to close a question as duplicate towards a question that doesn't fully address OP concerns. OP isn't concerned that the asker accepted their wrong answer (as in, it doesn't solve the problem is being asked), but instead something that they in hindsight would never recommend as solution to the problem, even when it solves it and specially if there are better ways to do the task. Also, the other question doesn't even fathom the quality of the question itself which this question actually address.

Comment: @ChrisF I defer to you moderators' better judgements.

Comment: Moderators are people too, they can make mistakes. Do not blidly trust the judgement of a single person or entity. That's why any social system collapses: lack of critical individual thinking.

Comment: @Braiam It's okay. Bhargav killed this before it became a HNQ, and Yvette's give me the answer I was looking for, so I don't care either way. I am curious to know whether this is an incorrect closure or not, but this thread is dead so you may consider opening another Meta to challenge this closure. I suspect you might be in the minority but you should be able to argue a good case.

Comment: No discussion is dead, just not interesting for the public at the moment. Even if you found *the* answer you were looking for, I think that the next guy wouldn't actually do everything in its power to make SO a better place as my answer suggest. Also, [for me, discussions can have many bells and whistles that may modify the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365682/792066)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I handled a similar mod flag recently in the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). The answerer (an expert in the tag) wanted his accepted upvoted answer deleted as he realised it was poor advice and he couldn't make it good through editing it. This was a high rep trusted user, so I accepted their expertise and deleted the answer.

Likewise, I'd recommend you do the same. As a high rep user with expertise in the tag, flag it for mod attention, stating the reason why.

Answer (score 3):

> Some answers to these **questions were rather poor themselves**

That they merit closure too? You know what you can do? Close the question, and then vote to delete the whole thing. None of your solutions is going to work, so just **use the privileges that you have gained to make the internet a better place**.

Comment: BTW, and before someone claims "but it's a singpost!" the thing was up for almost 365 days, and in that  timeframe it go only 130 views (and consider meta traffic). I bet too few searchers would find the target due that question.

Comment: Please don't abuse your gold tag badge privilege to reopen questions just so you can answer them.

Comment: @ChrisF I'm **not abusing my gold badge**, I saw that none of the questions asked what the OP knowingly or not was actually asking: I answered a bad question with an bad answer, and now i want to get rid of my answer, how do I do it?

Comment: Also, if a question really had 5 different duplicates, then it would be invariably too broad. This question isn't. The duplicates simply didn't apply to this specific context.

Comment: Why not post your answer on the duplicate target?

Comment: @ChrisF because my answer in no way address any of the duplicates. None of them are asking "my answer is bad and the question too, yet the answer was accepted and can't delete my bad answer to **a bad question**". My solution wouldn't work in none of those cases.